# Scrapy selector outside html tag

Tags: xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I have a special case where a script tag is placed outside the html tag :

```
<html>
....
</html>

<script>data</script>
```

both css and xpath selectors are not finding this script tag, the only way I found is using response.text , but that responds with a giant string and I can not make regex operations on it with selector re() function.

Is there a way to CSS or Xpath tags outside html tag?

I tried with

```
response.css('script')
```

But only consider script tags inside html tag

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction :

css selector does not consider tags outside HTML , xpath does.

I used some conditions to filter the tag :

```
response.xpath('//script[contains(., "function SelectItem()")]')
```